# Finding US immigration/travel documents for Ohio Denehy family from Ireland/Wales?

Tags: immigration, ireland

Looking for immigration/travel documents for:

Daniel Denehy: Born May 1858, Ireland moved to Youngstown Ohio and died 8 March 1912

Ellen Denehy/Connors: Born 1 March 1872 Tredegar, Blaenau Gwent, Wales Died 8 December 1950 in youngstown Ohio.

**Thomas A. Denehy:**Born 27 June 1888 Wales Died 29 August 1963 New Castle Pennsylvania and also lived in Youngstown Ohio.

Comment: Have you narrowed down the arrival date based on censuses and other records? A summary of US and UK records already found or reviewed would be very helpful.

Comment: http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/5426/104 would make an excellent starting point to help you with your search.

Comment: For others planning to assist on this question, travel seems to have been between births of Thomas (27 June 1888 Wales) and next sibling Maggie Denehy (born 29 October 1890 Youngstown, Mahoning, Ohio). No easy passenger list finds in ancestry databases; may have come through Canada or name badly mis-spelled.

Comment: I found their travel document, Daniel traveled here with Ellens brother Garrett O'Connors in 1887.

Comment: I think you should write up this finding as an answer to the question and then ask a new question about the travel of Ellen and Thomas.